# Using F# discriminated union alternative as parameter type

Tags: types, f#

I am trying to use a specific member of a discriminated union as a parameter type. For example:

```
type SomeUnion =
   | A of int * int
   | B of string

type SomeType(A(i, j)) =
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j

let a = A(10, 20)
let instance = SomeType(a)
```

but this is illegal syntax, and complains with "Unexpected symbol '(' in type definition" for SomeType's param list. This is valid syntax:

```
let doSomethingWithA (A(i, j)) = i + j
```

but the type signature is `SomeUnion -> int` rather than `A -> int`, and it complains about incomplete pattern match (understandable given the signature).

So is this possible? I believe in F# union members are compiled to CLR classes, so seems theoretically possible, but is it practically (i.e. without using something like reflection)? Otherwise I suppose you have to do the manual OOP way which is more verbose, and can't guarantee complete matches.

Comment: You don't want discriminated unions :) Either find something else, or rethink.

Comment: @RamonSnir well, most of the time I do want a discriminated union because I have a sealed set of choices that I want to be able to match over frequently. However occasionally I want to guarantee specifically one alternative and use its params. I'd prefer not to throw away the benefits of discriminated unions for these infrequent cases.

Comment: That's the case. You can't guarantee it since there is neither compiler nor runtime check that you receive a certain DU case as an argument.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it is surprising that you cannot pattern match the constructor argument. It *does* work with normal members.

Maybe you can do an explicit match in the constructor, to get a runtime error if the value is wrong:

```
type SomeType(a) =
    let i, j = match a with | A(k, l) -> k, l
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j
```

But otherwise, one must understand that `A` is **not** a type. So it is not surprising that the type of `doSomethingWithA` is not as you expected. And you would have to live with the incomplete pattern match warnings.

Comment: this still only infers `a` to be `SomeType` hence the incomplete match you mention. When you say `A` is not a type, in fact under the bonnet it is, as the compiler emits IL whereby each alternative is a nested class (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/09/17/adventures-in-f-discriminated-unions.aspx) for example). I am hoping someone can definitively confirm there is no natural F# way of handling this; certainly it is starting to look that way.

Comment: @fhusb: It is implemented an IL type. But on the F# language level, the DU cases are not accessible as types.

Answer (score 6):

As wmeyer points out, the "A" case of the DU is not a type at all, but is just a component of the union type.

If you really want to reuse one of the union cases on its own, I can't see any alternative to making it an explicit standalone type.

Option one is to just use a type alias:

```
type TypeA = int * int

type SomeUnion =
    | A of TypeA 
    | B of string

type SomeType(a:TypeA) =
    let (i,j) = a
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j

let a = (10, 20)
let instance = SomeType(a)
```

I have added the `TypeA` annotation in the constructor for clarity.

The second option is to wrap it in a single case DU.

```
type TypeA = TA of int * int

type SomeUnion =
    | A of TypeA 
    | B of string

type SomeType(a:TypeA) =
    let (TA(i,j)) = a  
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j

let a = TA (10, 20)
let instance = SomeType(a)
```

(Note that the match `let (TA(i,j)) = a` has to have extra parens so that it is not confused with a function.)

Answer (score 5):

My F# is a little rusty, but maybe you could do something like this (tested with f# 2 on mono)?

```
type SomeUnion =
   | A of int * int
   | B of string

type SomeType(i:int, j:int) =
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j

let createSomeType(SomeUnion.A(i,j)) = new SomeType(i,j)
let a = A(10, 20)
let instance = createSomeType(a)
```

Comment: This looks better, but means I'd have to create a function per type to pattern match and extract params. In the absence of some more natural language syntax is probably the best I can do